# use sql to delete a person from a list with a conflicting field

Tags: sql, db2

Hi I have table which asks a person for a yes/no answer, however some have said both yes and no i.e.:

```
person--------------status
1-------------------yes
2-------------------yes
3-------------------yes
3-------------------no
4-------------------no
5-------------------yes
5-------------------no
```

where persons 3 and 5 have two rows, one for 'yes' and one for 'no'.

What I want to find people with both answers, and delete the row which line which says 'no'. so i end up with:

```
person--------------status
1-------------------yes
2-------------------yes
3-------------------yes
4-------------------no
5-------------------yes
```

My logic is failing me and I can only get:

```
delete from table where status = 'no'
and where person in (select person from table where status = 'yes')
```

but of course this deletes both types.

anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `and where` is not SQL.  Try this:

```
delete from table
     where status = 'no' and
           person in (select person from table where status = 'yes')
```

The logic looks correct to me.

Comment: @paul . . . The OP said that the original query deleted both.  But, the original query had a syntax error.  The logic seems correct to me.

Comment: @paul See my answer, in which I tested this logic to prove it, and show the results.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is one way (there will be other ways too).

```
delete from table 
where status = 'no' and
      person in (select person from table 
                 where status in ('no', 'yes')
                 group by person 
                 having count(distinct status)>1)
```

Comment: Looks good but the original (once corrected) seems much simpler and a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: your solution should work, except maybe for the superfluous "where".

Answer (score 1):

It does **not** delete both, once you fix the syntax error of having an extra `where`.  It says delete where status = 'no' **`AND`** another condition is true.  Both must be true to delete the record.  If the record has 'yes', then clearly the conditions cannot both be true for that record since one of them is false.

So let's try this out in DB2:

```
create table survey 
  (person smallint
  ,answer   varchar(5)
  );

insert into survey
  values (1, 'yes'),
         (2, 'yes'),
         (3, 'yes'),
         (3, 'no'),
         (4, 'no'),
         (5, 'yes'),
         (5, 'no');
```

This gives me

```
person  answer
------  ------
  1     yes 
  2     yes 
  3     yes 
  3     no  
  4     no  
  5     yes 
  5     no
```

So, now the test

```
delete from survey 
  where answer = 'no'
    and person in (select person 
                     from survey 
                     where answer = 'yes'
                  );
```

My table now has

```
person  answer
------  ------
  1     yes 
  2     yes 
  3     yes 
  4     no  
  5     yes
```

It clearly did **not** delete both types, and has the desired result.

I am using DB2 for i 7.1, and perhaps others are using DB2 LUW.  But I find it very difficult to imagine that the fundamental logic of how basic SQL works (such as `AND`) could work drastically differently across different IBM platforms.